# Can someone explain the timing attack on RSA with Montgomery multiplication?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, attack, timing-attack, montgomery-multiplication

I have read several articles on the temporal attack against  Montgomery multiplication to speedup RSA computations. However, I do not quite get the principle.

I understood that there is a  additional reduction when performing Montgomery multiplication when the multiplication is greater than the modulus.

What I don't understand is how to choose the message sets. Or how to go from one key bit to another. And how many messages should be taken for each bit.

Edit : i'm still wondering on how we get the two sets of messages. The first set should not include a reduction in contrary to the second set. How can we know if there is a reduction or not ?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52214/rsa-timing-attack-on-extra-montgomery-reduction) yet?

Comment: Please indicate if you did. Your question could be closed as a duplicate if you don't. As it stands, it is unclear what part you don't get. There are 3 questions (I had to remove the "how to attack a little" because that's not really a good question). If you read the other answer, then where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes i do, i'm still wondering on how we get the two sets of messages. The first set should not include a reduction in contrary to the second set. How can we know if there is a reduction or not ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RSA Timing Attack on "Extra" Montgomery Reduction](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52214/rsa-timing-attack-on-extra-montgomery-reduction)

Comment: I read it several times, but i dont understand this part "plays all messages" in the first answer.